# Как в Django позволить добавлять экземпляр только для конкретного родителя родителя

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Задача такая:
Есть классы: **Соревнование**, **Гимнаст** и **Результат**.
Класс **Гимнаст** имеет `ForeignKey` для класса **Соревнование**.
Класс **Результат** имеет `ForeignKey` для класса **Гимнаст**.
Как в форме для создания экземпляра **Результат** сначала выбрать нужное соревнование, а только потом необходимого **Гимнаста**?

```
class Competition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Gymnast(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Competition, related_name='gymnasts')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Result(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Gymnast, related_name='results')

    score1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score2 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score3 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score4 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score5 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score6 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score7 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948018/django-admin-add-custom-form-fields-that-are-not-part-of-the-model) показывают как добавить новое поле в админку и при этом не сохранять его в модель.
Так-же есть модуль [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form), который поможет отфильтровать одно поле в зависимости от другого.

Задача сводится к:

1. Добавить поле competition
2. Поле parent сделать зависимым от
   competition

**Пример** добавления своего поля из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948018/django-admin-add-custom-form-fields-that-are-not-part-of-the-model):

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_field = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        extra_field = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field', None)
        # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super(YourModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

**Пример** изменения списка элементов в зависимости от другого поля (в нашем случае, мы его добавили выше) в форме админ панели (из [документации](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form)):

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONTINENT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'birth_country': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='country-autocomplete',
                                                       forward=['continent'])
        }
```

И, собственно, **пример** вью (из [документации](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form)), которая будет отвечать за выгрузку списка гимнастов отфильтрованного по соревнованиям:

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Country.objects.none()

        qs = Country.objects.all()

        continent = self.forwarded.get('continent', None)

        if continent:
            qs = qs.filter(continent=continent)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

Comment: Только ссылка не является ответом. Добавте основное из ссылок прямо в тело ответа.